# Spring Webflow action defined on-render is not being called in a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I'm trying to unit-test a simple Spring Webflow. So far I can verify transitions between the states and check variables in the request, flash, view and flow scopes.

Somehow I cannot verify that an on-render action is executed. When I run the webflow in my web application, I can see the select populated with the results of that action, so the definition must be fine. When I debug through the Spring Webflow, I can see that there are no event listeners, but I cannot quite figure out why the array of the listeners is not being populated.

I'll keep digging through the code, but I wonder if anyone faced the same issue and how it was resolved.

If this is relevant, I am mocking the service with Mockito and injecting it by overriding configureFlowBuilderContext() and registering the mock service as a bean.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this problem earlier today while trying to write a test for a new feature in a terrifying legacy Spring Web Flow app. I don't pretend to have an expert understanding of Spring Web Flow, but diving into the code, `<on-render>` seemed to trigger off of `ViewState.render(...)`, which is called from `ViewState.resume(...)` and `ViewState.doEnter(...)`. There are some nasty nested `if-else` blocks there, but it looked like it all depended on the `responseAllowed` and `responseComplete` attributes of the `ExternalContext.`

The reason that only the first `<on-render>` block would be executed in tests is because the `MockExternalContext` from Spring defaults to a a `null` `responseAllowed` and never changes `responseComplete` back to false after the first response. So I've tricked the flow into executing `<on-render>` attributes by writing my own implementation of the `ExternalContext interface`.

I literally copy-pasted the existing `MockExternalContext` with the following two changes:

- Set `responseAllowed` to default to true:

  `private Boolean responseAllowed = true;`
- Overwrite the `recordResponseComplete` function to never set the response to complete:

  `public void recordResponseComplete() {
      //responseComplete = true;  (Yes, this is literally just commented out)
  }`

Soooo this is a hideous hack and probably has side effects, but Spring Web Flow is a hideous framework anyway, and this solution worked for me. YMMV.